# Notational question on Cartan Decomposition of Semisimple Lie Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I've often wondered why in every book of Lie algebra the Cartan Decomposition in written as
$$\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h}\oplus\underset{{\scriptscriptstyle \lambda\in\Phi}}{\bigoplus}\mathfrak{g}_{\lambda},$$
instead of
$$\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h} \underset{{\scriptscriptstyle \lambda\in\Phi}}{\bigoplus}\mathfrak{g}_{\lambda}.$$
Is it just a notational convention or there's some deeper reason that I'm missing for this notation? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Thinking of $\mathfrak{h}$ and $\underset{{\scriptscriptstyle \lambda\in\Phi}}{\bigoplus}\mathfrak{g}_{\lambda}$ as two distinct things, one really should have an $\oplus$ in between them when taking the direct sum. The second thing you write doesn't really express this, $\underset{{\scriptscriptstyle \lambda\in\Phi}}{\bigoplus}\mathfrak{g}_{\lambda}$ is a direct sum of the root spaces $\mathfrak{g}_\lambda$, but then the $\mathfrak{h}$ is just sitting there in front of them.

Comment: Ok, fair enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is just an expansion of Ben West's comment:

If we write $\Phi=\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_d\}$, then
$$\bigoplus_{\lambda\in\Phi}\mathfrak{g}_\lambda=\mathfrak{g}_{\lambda_1}\oplus\cdots\oplus \mathfrak{g}_{\lambda_d}$$
so
$$\mathfrak{h}\bigoplus_{\lambda\in\Phi}\mathfrak{g}_\lambda=\mathfrak{h}\mathfrak{g}_{\lambda_1}\oplus\cdots\oplus \mathfrak{g}_{\lambda_d}$$
which doesn't make any sense.